# phpmyadmin install on Debian 10 fails. [proxy_fcgi:error]: error parsing URL //: Invalid host/port

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to upgrade a phpmyadmin install on a (remote, VM) Debian 10 without success.

I followed install instructions at [computingforgeeks.com](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-phpmyadmin-with-apache-on-debian/), and at first - when i tried to access http://path.tld/phpmyadmin -  I just got a `The connection was reset` msg.

Thanks to a [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162762/apache2-4-php-fpm-phpmyadmin-in-debian) by [papasj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2964608/papasj), I checked that I may get a fine response for http://path.tld/phpmyadmin/test.html (test.html file under /usr/share/phpmyadmin), hence the issue should be that php files under /usr/share/phpmyadmin are not being processed.

I tried a hint by [papasj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2964608/papasj) to include a `ProxyPassMatch` line within `/etc/apache2/conf-available//etc/apache2/conf-available`:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/phpmyadmin/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/var/run/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi:///usr/share/phpmyadmin/
```

and things improved a little, since now I get a `Bad Request  Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand`. Apache2 error.log claims that `[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid .....] [client .....] AH01059: error parsing URL //: Invalid host/port`. I am not sure how to understand/fix the last error. I tried a few variants for the `ProxyPassMatch` line, without any success.

- Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
- PHP 8.1.9
- System  4.19.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP
  Debian 4.19.249-2 (2022-06-30) x86_64
- Server API FPM/FastCGI

Within `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` I see `listen = /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock`.

`systemctl status php8.1-fpm.service` and `systemctl status apache2` reply fine.

`FPM/FastCGI`, `ProxyPassMatch`, .... is uncharted territory for me,
I have been stuck for a couple of days, and I appreciate your help.

Comment: how did you installed the pma initially?

Comment: @djdomi I am not sure, I did not do the first install. I guess it was shipped with Debian 10. I updated php to 8.1 (from 7.3) since I need  to install Symfony 6, and so I need to upgrade pma too. (I know that I could install pma anew under my web server root, but I would like to fix what is already there).

Comment: `apt --reinstall install phpmyadmin` I am atm not sure if the package is still this name

Comment: `$apt --reinstall install phpmyadmin   >>>
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
Package phpmyadmin is not available, but is referred to by another package.  
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or  
is only available from another source`

Comment: you need to use search for phpmyadmin to see what has been used, but I already stated this that I am not aware about the correct name

Comment: `$# apt search phpmyadmin adminer/oldstable 4.7.1-1 all   phpliteadmin/oldstable 1.9.7.1-2+deb10u1 all   phpliteadmin-themes/oldstable 1.9.7.1-2+deb10u1 all`.  Uhm, uhm, it seems they don't ship phpmyadmin anymore. I am not sure I want to move to Admirer. It should be possible to install the pma  i got  by `wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/${VERSION}/phpMyAdmin`.

Comment: admin er is EOL

Comment: @djdomi Do you mean phpmyadmin is EOL? Really? How is it?

Comment: adminer damn auto correction